# Looking for better solution

Tags: vb.net, for-loop

I have the following code.

Surely there must be a better way of coding this using a for/next or something, but I just don't get it to work

```
    If CheckBox1.CheckState Then bin(1) = "1" Else bin(1) = "0"   
    If CheckBox2.CheckState Then bin(2) = "1" Else bin(2) = "0"
    If CheckBox3.CheckState Then bin(3) = "1" Else bin(3) = "0"
    ..
    ..
    ..
    If CheckBox20.CheckState Then bin(20) = "1" Else bin(20) = "0"
```

Comment: Welcome to stack Willy. Please make the title of your question more detailed and about your problem. Please also post what you have tried so far. If you think a for-loop is needed then research that and try it with a for-loop. There's loads of documentation on how to do that.

Comment: Hint: you can put references to the checkboxes in an array, like `Dim cbs = {CheckBox1, CheckBox2, CheckBox3}` then use `For i = 0 to cbs.Length - 1` to iterate over that array. Remember that arrays in VB.NET start at an index of 0, not 1.

Comment: Thank you  guys for the detailed solutions. I'm going to try them out

Answer (score 1):

OK, This should work, but bear in mind, it assumes that you have 20 `CheckBoxes` and that number will never change, and that the `bin` array will also never change the number of elements.

```
Private Sub SyncCheckBoxestoBinValue()
    For i As Integer = 1 To 20
        bin(i) = Math.Abs(CInt(CType(Me.Controls("CheckBox" & i), CheckBox).Checked)).ToString
    Next
End Sub
```

An explanation might be in order here. Working from the inside out, here goes..

`Me.Controls("CheckBox" & i)`

This will refer to the control that matches `CheckBox1` when `i=1`, `CheckBox2` when `i=2` etc. However, because that bit of code is designed to work with all kinds of control, it can only return it as an Object type rather than the specific type of control you're searching for.

To be able to do anything significant with that result, we need to tell the compiler that it's a `CheckBox`. So now we need to wrap that last bit of code in to this.

`CType(Me.Controls("CheckBox" & i), CheckBox)`

Now we have something that the compiler recognises as a `CheckBox`, we can work with it. So you want to find out of the `CheckBox is checked or not. You've used`Checkstate`, but personally I think it's a bit easier to use`Checked` for this purpose. So ...

`CType(Me.Controls("CheckBox" & i), CheckBox).Checked`

This returns a result of `True` or `False`. In VB.Net this can also be seen as -1 (true) or 0 (false). although you want a 1 or 0 so that you can assign this value to your `bin` array. How we do this is as below

`Math.Abs(CInt(CType(Me.Controls("CheckBox" & i), CheckBox).Checked)).ToString`

Finally, your result of 1 or 0 is assigned to the element of `bin` that corresponds to the `CheckBox` number

That "should" do it.

Comment: More duh :) tyvm

Answer (score 0):

Maybe make the check boxes a list and query the result by `linq`? For the sake of <s>using linq for everything</s> better readability, I mean.

```
Dim cbList = New List(Of CheckBox) From {checkBox1, checkBox2, checkBox3}
Dim binTmp As List(Of String) = cbList.Select(Function(chk) If(chk.checkState, "1", "0")).ToList()
bin = binTmp
```

You may also want to store the result as `Boolean` instead of "1","0" for further processing.